# EVE Online - questions about station trading

Tags: eve-online

I've got an alt that's engaged solely in station trade, I had a few questions maybe some other more experienced traders could answer:

1. Do you put all the money in your possession into buy orders, or do you leave a little in your wallet? My plan was to have this alt generating income with which to fund other activities, but I can see that I'm not making the most of my ISK. What do you do with your money?
2. Is there any way to be notified of which orders have been completely filled? Would I need to rely on an external application to do so? I ask because I've run into times where I fill up my buy orders with stuff, but I don't remember the exact quantities that I'd set so when I get back, I see lots of goods in my hangar but no buy order. It'd be great if I had some way to refer both to the quantity set in the original order as well as the price (aside from the in-game transaction journal)

Comment: Try this program: www.evementat.com/

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes! The more ISK you have tied up in Buy orders (which should be a combination of high-quantity+low-price orders and low-quantity+high-price orders), the faster you'll be acquiring the goods you need.  Having lots of input goods should mean you can then use those to create a lot of large Sell orders.  Which is what will generate all the sweet iskies.
2. [EveMon](http://evemon.battleclinic.com/) will do this (and much more!) for you.  There's a tab that notifies you of recent changes in your buy and sell orders.  The notification type changes based on whether the order was partially or completely filled.  Much easier to read than the transaction journal.

Comment: For a serious trader I would recommend EveMentat over EveMon. www.evementat.com/